# ¿Cómo dividir un número en partes iguales y que la suma de todas las partes sean == a 100 ? Python

Tags: python

Ejemplo: quiero dividir **100 / 3** y que cada una de sus partes sume **100** si no suman **100** entonces aproximar una de ellas para de la suma total de 100

**100 / 3 = 33.3333333333333** pero siempre va faltar un pedazo para completar **100** , entonces **se podría redondear una de sus partes.**

Muchísimas Gracias a quien me pueda ayudar

Comment: ¿Quieres decir tres partes enteras, como 33, 33 y 34? O te refieres al problema de los infinitos decimales que sumarian 99.99999999 en vez de 100?

Comment: Si , quiero dividirlo  en partes enteras

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se me ocurre el siguiente algoritmo. Tienes un número `N` (digamos 100) que quieres dividir en `m` partes enteras aproximadamente iguales (digamos `m=3`), de modo que las partes difieran como máximo en una unidad.

Puedes comenzar haciendo la división entera de `N//m` (en este ejemplo sale 33), y crear así `m` partes iguales con ese valor: `[33, 33, 33]`

Por otro lado calculando el resto de la división (`N%m`) sacarás los que han "sobrado" y que habrá que repartir entre los grupos formados. En este caso `100%3` da resto 1, así que hay una unidad a añadir a uno de las partes antes halladas, dando el resultado final `[34, 33, 33]`.

Otro ejemplo, `N=100` pero `m=7`. Entonces `N//m` sale 14 y el resto `N%m` es 2. Así que tendrás 7 grupos de valor 14 y a dos de ellos les sumas 1, para dar 15, con lo que el resultado queda `[15, 15, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14]`

Fíjate que ya que el resto es siempre menor a `m`, en esta última fase en la que repartes ese resto entre los grupos antes formados habrá siempre grupos que se queden "como estaban", mientras que otros recibirán una unidad más. Este es el reparto más equitativo posible y asegura que o bien todos los grupos son iguales, o la diferencia entre ellos no es superior a 1.

Esta idea se implementa en el siguiente código:

```
N = 100
m = 3

trozos = [ N//m ] * m    # La lista con m trozos iniciales

# Ahora el reparto de las unidades sobrantes
resto = N % m
for i in range(resto):
  trozos[i]+=1
```

El resultado será `trozos = [34, 33, 33]`. Puedes probar otros valores y ver que funciona.

### Añadido

Si no quieres el resultado en una lista, sino imprimir solo cuántos grupos se forman y cuántos elementos tiene cada uno, la cosa quedaría así:

```
N = 100
m = 3

c = N // m
r = N % m

print(f"División de {N} en {m} grupos:")
print(f"{r} grupos de {c+1} elementos y {m-r} grupos de {c} elementos")
```

Comment: Si sr , es una respuesta que cumple con lo esperado, muchísimas gracias amigo